# Как изменить информацию в базе данных через php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

у меня есть форма для заполнения данных пользователем на которой выводится статья и информация о ней. Выглядит она так:

```
<form action='admin_panel.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<label>
    Название статьи:<br>
    <input type='text' name='article_title1' size='60' value='$article_title' required/><br>
</label>
    <label>
    Изображние к статье:<br>
    <input type='file' name='article_image1' size='60' /><br>
</label>
<label>
    Введите текст статьи:<br>
    <textarea class='txtar' name='article_text1' required>$article_text</textarea><br>
</label>
<a href='news.php'>Вернуться назад</a><br><br>
<label>
    <input type='submit' name='insertarticle1' value='Ввести данные'/>
</label>
</form>
```

Код для изменения данных в бд выглядит так:

```
If(isset($_POST['insertarticle'])){
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blshk") ;
        //getting the text data from the fields
    $art_edit = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['art_edit']);
        $article_title1 = $_POST['article_title1'];
        $article_text1 = $_POST['article_text1'];
        $article_image1 = $_FILES['article_image1']['name'];
        $article_image_tmp1 = $_FILES['article_image1']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($article_image_tmp1,"images/$article_image1");
        $insertarticle =  mysql_query("UPDATE article SET article_title='$article_title1',  article_text='$article_text1', article_image='$article_image1' WHERE article_id='$art_edit',",$link);

        if($insertarticle=='TRUE'){

        echo "<script>alert('article inserted')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('admin_panel.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    }
```

Однако он не работает. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: И не будет работать `mysqli_connect()` c `mysql_query()`. Это разные библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_connect()` Это одна библиотека и если использовать mysqli, то на всех местах надо  писать mysqli, а у вас в

```
$insertarticle =  mysql_query("UPDATE article SET 
  article_title='$article_title1',  article_text='$article_text1',
  article_image='$article_image1' WHERE article_id='$art_edit',",$link);
```

написано `mysql` вместо `msqli`. Библиотека `mysqli` это новый и улучшенный вид `mysql`.